# Spring JPA 2.4 not Mapping Booleans Correctly in PostgreSQL database

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, spring-boot, hibernate

I have been using Spring Boot 2.3.3.RELEASE with Java 11 and Spring Boot Starter Data JPA for integration with my PostgreSQL database, version 12.5. I upgraded to Spring 2.4.0 (Hibernate Core 5.4.25.Final), and now any time I try to get an entity that has a boolean field from the database, it throws the following exception:

```
org.hibernate.PropertyAccessException: Null value was assigned to a property [class com.x.database.User.taxExempt] of primitive type setter of com.x.database.User.taxExempt
```

Here is the code for taxExempt:

```
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "tax_exempt", nullable = false)
    private boolean taxExempt;
```

Everything worked fine in 2.3.3.RELEASE (Hibernate Core 5.4.20.Final)

I switched the field to a boxed Boolean, which prevented the exception, but User.taxExempt was still showing as null in the debugger. The column in the database is not null, and all records in that table have a value for that column.

Is this an issue with the Postgres driver? According to their website, the latest version of the driver is compatible up to Java 9, but everything worked before with Java 11 before I changed the Spring version.

Comment: is there a 'not null' constaint on the column?

Comment: There is a 'not null' constraint on the column.

Comment: Your `@NotNull` is useless on a primitive. However something must be returning `null` from the database and `null` cannot be converted to a `boolean`.

Comment: Yes - what is interesting is that all records are either true or false, but the error is still happening. I want to reiterate that this issue does not happen in Spring 2.3.3.RELEASE.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use non-primitive wrapper types; e.g., `Boolean` instead of `boolean`,  `Integer` instead of `int`.

A `null` value cannot be assigned to a `primitive` type, like `int`, `long`, `boolean`, etc. If the database column that corresponds to the field in your object can be null, then your field should be a wrapper class, like `Integer`, `Long`, `Boolean`, etc.

So your field should look like below.

```
@NotNull
@Column(name = "tax_exempt", nullable = false)
private Boolean taxExempt;
```

Comment: Switching to a boxed Boolean avoids the PropertyAccessException, but the field is still getting set to null. The column in the DB has a not null constraint, and all records have values for that column. I want to reiterate that this issue does not happen in Spring 2.3.3.RELEASE.